# SQL Server - Merge 3 temp table columns adjacent to each

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created 3 temporary tables, where each temporary table holds two lines of data. But when I used the UNION command I end up having 6 lines of data, where I was expecting to have only two lines.

JFI, 1st Temp table holds 8 Fields (columns), 2nd Temp table holds 7 & 3rd Temp table holds 6.

I am looking for a solution where the 2nd & 3rd table columns/values should endup after the 1st table columns,

expected outcome to have 2 rows across 21 columns

expected columns

T1_Col1,T1_Col2,T1_Col3,T1_Col4,T1_Col5,T1_Col6,T1_Col7,T1_Col8  ,T2_Col1,T2_Col2,T2_Col3,T2_Col4,T2_Col5,T2_Col6,T2_Col7  ,T3_Col1,T3_Col2,T3_Col3,T3_Col4,T3_Col5

Comment: UNION is for appending results.  You are looking to JOIN the tables together.

Comment: Smashing, worked using the JOIN command. silly I couldn't figured that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should be using the JOIN Function to add the Table 2 & Table 3 columns adjacent.

Note: you need have at least 1 primary key across ALL three tables to make the join

E.g.
Select * from #Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN #Table2 T2 ON T1.PrimaryKey = T2.PrimaryKey 
    INNER JOIN #Table3 T3 ON T1.PrimaryKey = T3.PrimaryKey